# When explicitly initializing std::optional's, should I use nullopt?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, idioms

An `std::optional<T>` can be initialized to the disengaged state like so:

```
std::optional<int> oi { nullopt };
```

but also like so:

```
std::optional<int> oi { };
```

and similarly for assignment (`oi = {}` or `oi = nullopt`).

Other than personal preference / sense of aesthetics, is there a difference between these which should make me prefer one over the other? Or does it not matter at all?

**Note:** I'm asking about cases where I want to explicitly initialize the optional, rather than default-initialize it (e.g. for emphasis).

Comment: How have you been initializing your disengaged `std::function`s and `std::shared_ptr`s and `std::unique_ptr`s so far?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I've actually not been using disengaged functions, shared_ptr's or unique_ptr's so far - I always construct them engaged. I've lived a sheltered life...

Comment: It can also be initialized like this: `std::optional<int> oi;`, which is probably the version I would use if I could choose.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Also `std::optional<int> oi = nullopt;`, if you're not one of the braces-everywhere crowd but still want to be explicit. (Hah: "explicit", but not `explicit` :-) .)

Comment: @KerrekSB Wait. We forgot all about `auto io = std::optional<int>();` and variants thereof.

Comment: @juanchopanza: See clarification.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I think the "always auto" crowd is largely the same as the "braces everywhere" one, though :-)

Comment: @Jarod42: Trying to make the phrasing elicit less opinion-based responses.

Comment: It does seem to have performance implications (depending on the implementation). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964217/stdoptional-construct-empty-with-or-stdnullopt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both have the same effect - I would prefer the simplest form (KISS), but it is subjective, pick one and be consistent. You may also wish to be consistent with how you treat other objects in your code, do you normally rely on default initialization (e.g. `int i{}` vs `int i{0}`)?

Personally when I see redundant code, like initalizing an object to its default value explicitly, it does reduce my confidence in the author by a slight margin - does the author really understand what he is doing and trying to be extra safe / explicit / readable, or was he simply too lazy to read the documentation? It makes me wonder, does the author understand what happens when he writes `std::vector<std::optional> v(n)`, or more complex examples? If this is a documented decision, in a coding style, then all is fine, I can understand the need to improve readability.

Comment: I rely on default initialization a lot, but very often I differentiate between "I don't care what the value is" and "I want you to notice I'm setting this value by default". Especially if I have several fields - some I might default-initializ while others I'll explicitly initialized to some value (which might just be the default value).

Answer (score 10):

It does not matter at all. Choose whatever makes your colleagues understand your code better.

Comment: so, probably `nullopt` then, since the brain makes just a little less effort figuring that out instead of "hmm, what will happen if I use empty braces"?

Comment: @einpoklum: Yeah, but beware that you're working with a false dichotomy. The comments under the question point out to several further options that you should all weigh against one another. (Personally, I'd use either default-initialization or "= nullopt;".)

Comment: @einpoklum As a matter of opinion, I find using `{}` to mean "meh, nothing there" (like the empty set) is a really strong idiom in my code in modern C++.  It works when returning many maybe-empty things like containers or optionals or std functions.  The details of `nullopt` is irrelevant.  In other contexts, an actual `nullopt` is needed (for example, `?:`).