# When are trivial constructors (or destructors or assignment operators) important for efficiency?

Tags: c++

As we know, there is a difference between

```
struct S {
    int x;
    S() = default;
    S(const S& other) = default;
};
```

and:

```
struct S {
    int x;
    S() noexcept {}
    S(const S& other) noexcept : x(other.x) {}
};
```

In the first case, the default constructor and copy constructor are trivial. In the second case, they are nontrivial, even though they do the same thing as the trivial versions.

In what situations can the first definition of `S` result in more efficient code generation than the second definition, **assuming a good optimizing compiler with optimizations turned on?**

I know that if compiler optimizations are off, then the compiler may generate calls to nontrivial `S::S` functions (whereas the trivial default constructor is a no-op, and the trivial copy constructor is just a `MOV` instruction or similar). However, with optimizations on, the compiler would just inline the nontrivial constructors, and there wouldn't be any difference in simple situations.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but value-initializing the first `struct S` will zero the `x`, so, for example, storing it in standard containers (w/ default allocator) could be slightly slower.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Related to your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964217/9171697