# Is std::optional set to std::nullopt when it is declared as a local variable and not explicitly initialized?

Tags: c++, stl, stdoptional

When an `int` is declared locally (but not initialized or assigned to), it is of undefined value. When `std::optional<int>` is declared locally without an explicit initialization, does the same apply? Is it always `std::nullopt`, or is it of undefined value?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964217/stdoptional-construct-empty-with-or-stdnullopt

Answer (score 5):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) for `std::optional` constructors:

> `constexpr optional() noexcept;`
>
> `constexpr optional( std::nullopt_t ) noexcept;`
>
> Constructs an object that does not contain a value.

So yes, a default initialized `std::optional` has no value, but it's not indeterminate.

Comment: Is the constructor called when the object is declared locally but not initialized?

Comment: Yes, declaring an `optional` object does call the constructor.

Comment: @jhourback "Is the constructor called when the object is declared locally but not initialized?" - Yes, the default constructor is called in that case.

Comment: My interpretation is that an `int` declared locally will NOT be default-initialized, but that  an `std::optional` declared locally will be default-initialized by calling the default constructor. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, an `int` that is uninitialized has an indeterminate value. Note that this is still default-initialization of the int, it's just that default-initialization leaves the int with an indeterminate value.

Comment: @jhourback An `int` declared as `int i;` *is* default initialized, it's just that `int`s don't have constructors and "default initialization" in that case means "has indeterminate value". `std::optional` on the other hand *does* have a default constructor that initialises the object to the value of `std::nullopt`. Just like the default constructor of a `std::string` initialises the object to an empty string. Default initialization is *not* the same as *zero initialization*.