# Is default constructor is better than user defined in C++11 if it's exactly the same?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

How is the compiler-generated constructor more efficient than the one we provide, if we provide exactly the same constructor?

i.e., does the compiler add *any extra code* to its default constructor, such that providing our own user-defined constructor is less efficient?

Simply put, how is default constructor generated in:

```
struct widget
{
  // default ctor generated
};
```

More efficient than the one provided in this:

```
struct widget
{
  widget(){} // user-defined but exactly the same
};
```

Comment: There are cases where the compiler will not create a default constructor, but you still need one. Then the `= default` ting comes in very handy. Otherwise not su much.

Comment: If you define your own constructor, C++ *WON'T* automatically generate a default (no-arg) constructor. Consequently,  `widget()=default` becomes useful if you want your own constructor *AND* you also want a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `widget() = default;` (in the class body only), the resulting constructor is exactly the same as the generated one.

Those two have an obscure property that `widget() {}` doesn't have: [value-initializing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) such a class would value-initialize all fields that would otherwise be uninitialized.

Example:

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    int y = 1;
    // This changes nothing:
    // A() = default;
};

struct B
{
    int x;
    int y = 1;
    B() {}
};

A a1;   // `x` is uninitialized    `y` is 1
A a2{}; // `x` is 0                `y` is 1
B b1;   // `x` is uninitialized    `y` is 1
B b2{}; // `x` is uninitialized    `y` is 1
```

Only use `widget() = default;` or the generated constructor if you want to take advantage of having two distinct initialization strategies, **or** if you don't have uninitialized members.

Otherwise use `widget() {}` to make sure you don't accidentally perform useless initialization.

Libstdc++ has fallen into this trap with their `std::optional` implementation, see [std::optional - construct empty with {} or std::nullopt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964217/2752075)

Answer (score -1):

> How is the compiler-generated constructor more efficient than the one we provide, if we provide exactly the same constructor?

It isn't, they generate the same code in reasonable compilers.

But there is nothing that forces a compiler to generate the exact same code. As long as the observable behavior is the same..

> i.e., does the compiler add any extra code to its default constructor, such that providing our own user-defined constructor is less efficient?

No, in reasonable compilers.